# how to change format for numbering statements so that number comes first

Tags: numbering

I was wondering how the format for numbering statements can be changed so that the statement number precedes the word "Theorem" or "Definition".  For example, I use the following code:

```
\newtheorem{Theorem}[Lemma]{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem} \label{thmOnSomething} 
Here is the theorem statement.
\end{Theorem}
```

The output looks like this:

**Theorem 1.2.27** *Here is the theorem statement.*

How can I change the code so that the output is as follows:

**1.2.27. Theorem:** *Here is the theorem statement.*

Comment: Do you load `amsthm` or any other related package. Please add a complete minimal working example.

Comment: if you're using `amsthm`, just insert `\swapnumbers` before the first `\newtheorem`.  documented in the user's guide: `texdoc amsthdoc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the base LaTeX the solution may be as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}


\chapter{One}
\section{Oneone}


\makeatletter
\def\@begintheorem#1#2{\trivlist
%   \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2}]\itshape}
\item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #2.\ #1:}]\itshape}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{tw}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{tw}
1+1=2
\end{tw}

\section{Twotwo}

\begin{tw}
1+1=2
\end{tw}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Because the style of numbering depends on class, there is a full example with the class `book`. The main trick is in the line below the commented one.